# Adding Unlimited Form Fields With JQuery and Saving to a Database with multiple rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, html

```
$rs1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM companydetails ORDER BY companyname");    
$customerlist="<option value=''></option>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs1))
{        
    $customerlist.="<OPTION VALUE=".$row["comid"]." >";
    $customerlist.=$row["companyname"]."</OPTION>";        
}

$query_parent = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `material` order by `marterial_name`") or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error());
$material='<option value=""></option>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent))
{   
    $material.="<option value=" .$row["id"].">";
    $material.=$row["marterial_name"]."</option>";
}                                                                                                                                      
$query_parent1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `material_location` order by `location`") or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error());

$exclusivetax=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM exclusive_tax ORDER BY id");    
$tax='<option value=""></option>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($exclusivetax))
{                
    $tax.="<OPTION VALUE=".$row["id"]." >";
    $tax.=$row["tax"]."</OPTION>";
}

$rs1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quotation_type ORDER BY type");    
$purchase_type='<option value=""></option>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs1))
{                
    $purchase_type.="<OPTION VALUE=".$row["id"]." >";
    $purchase_type.=$row["type"]."</OPTION>";
}    

$rs1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cz where (role='purchase' or role='sales' or role='Repair' or role='admin' or role='CSM' or role='Teamleader' or role='Superuser') and status='Active' order by username");
$u="<OPTION VALUE=''></OPTION>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs1))
{
    $u.="<OPTION VALUE=".$row["email2"]." >";
    $u.=$row["email2"]."</OPTION>";
    //$email2=$row["email2"];
}    

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Cp1252">
<script language="javascript" src="../calendar/calendar.js"></script>
<link href="../calendar/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/custombox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.searchabledropdown-1.0.8.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var $old = $.noConflict();
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/custombox.css">
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
        $me=$(this).val();
        $.get('loadsubcat.php?parent_cat=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#sub_cat").html(data);    
        });    
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.get('pdetail.php', function(data) {
        $("#users").html(data);    
        });

    $("#category").change(function() {
        $me=$(this).val();
        $.get('pdetail.php?category=' + $me, function(data) {
            $("#users").html(data);    
            });

        });        
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
        $me=$(this).val();

    });
        $("#sub_cat").change(function() {
            $me1=$(this).val();

            $.get('material_type.php?parent_cat=' + $me + '& sub_cat=' + $me1 , function(data) {
                $("#sub_cat11").html(data);
        });    
    });

});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
        $me=$(this).val();
        });
    $("#sub_cat").change(function() {
        $me1=$(this).val();
        });       

        });    
    });    
    $(function () {
        $('#stock').on('click', function ( e ) {
            Custombox.open({
                target: 'view_stock_full_detail.php?id=1& material=' + $me + '& maker='+ $me1 +'& type=' + $me2,
                effect: 'fadein',
                escKey: true,
                overlaySpeed: 100,
                overlayClose: true,
                speed: 100
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });        
});

</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ($) 
    {
        //initilize any plugins that need the newer version of jquery
        var counter = 2;

           $("#addButton").click(function () 
           {                
            if(counter>10)
            {
                alert("You can add only 10 Material Details");
                return false;
            }   
            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
             .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter)
             .attr("style",'margin-top:10px;margin-left:2px;');
            newTextBoxDiv.after().html( '<table border="1px" BORDERCOLOR="#98AFC7">'+
                                            '<tr>'+
                                                '<td width="100px">'+
                                                     '<div  style="width:150;height:20px; float:left; text-align:center">'+
                                                         '<font size="+1">Material:</font>'+
                                                     '</div>'+
                                                 '</td>'+
                                                 '<td width="200px">'+
                                                      '<div style="float:left;margin-left:20px;">'+
                                                           '<select class="nav" name="parent_cat1[]" id="parent_cat' + counter + '"> <?php echo $material; ?> </select>'+
                                                       '</div>'+
                                                 '</td>'+
                                                 '<td width="100">'+
                                                      '<div  style="width:100;height:20px; text-align:center">'+
                                                           '<font size="+1">Make:</font>'+
                                                      '</div>'+
                                                 '</td>'+
                                                 '<td>'+
                                                      '<div style="float:left;margin-left:20px;">'+
                                                          '<select class="nav" name="sub_cat1[]" id="sub_cat'+ counter +'"></select>'+
                                                      '</div>'+
                                                 '</td>'+
                                            '</tr>'+
                                        '</table>'+
                                        '<table border="1px" BORDERCOLOR="#98AFC7">'+
                                             '<tr>'+
                                                 '<td width="100">'+
                                                     '<div style="width:150;height:20px; float:left; text-align:center">'+
                                                          '<font size="+1">Type:</font>'+
                                                     '</div>'+
                                                 '</td>'+
                                                 '<td>'+ 
                                                     '<div style="float:left;margin-left:20px;">'+
                                                          '<select class="nav" name="sub_cat111[]" id="sub_cat11'+ counter +'"></select>'+
                                                     '</div>'+
                                                 '</td>'+
                                                 '<td>'+
                                                     '<div style="width:100px;height:20px;text-align:center">'+
                                                         '<font size="+1">Quantity:</font>'+
                                                     '</div>'+
                                                 '</td>'+
                                                 '<td>'+
                                                     '<div  style="margin-left:20px;">'+
                                                         '<input type="text" name="quantity1[]" id="quantity">'+
                                                     '</div>'+
                                                 '</td>'+
                                                 '<td>'+
                                                     '<div  id="stock' + counter +'" name="stock" style="width:150px;height:20px;text-align:center; margin-left:20px;"></div>'+
                                                 '</td>'+
                                             '</tr>'+
                                             '<tr>'+


                                                 '<td>'+
                                                     '<div style="width:100px;height:20px;text-align:center">'+
                                                         '<font size="+1">Sales Detail:</font>'+
                                                     '</div>'+
                                                 '</td>'+
                                                 '<td>'+
                                                     '<div  style="margin-left:20px;">'+
                                                         '<textarea rows="2" cols="25" name="s_price1[]" id="s_price" ></textarea>'+
                                                     '</div>'+
                                                 '</td>'+
                                                 '<td>'+
                                                    '<div style="margin-left:20px;width:100px;">'+
                                                        '<input type="checkbox" name="s_including1[]" id="including" value="including"><font size="+0">Including</font>'+
                                                        '<input type="checkbox" name="s_including1[]" id="excluding" value="excluding"><font size="+0">Excluding</font>'+
                                                        '<select class="nav" name="s_excluding_tax1[]" id="p_excluding_tax' + counter + '"> <?php echo $tax; ?> </select>'+
                                                    '</div>'+

                                                    '<td>'+
                                                     '<div style="width:100px;height:20px;text-align:center">'+
                                                         '<font size="+1">Price:</font>'+
                                                     '</div>'+
                                                 '</td>'+
                                                 '<td>'+
                                                     '<div  style="margin-left:20px;">'+
                                                         '<input type="text" name="price1[]" id="price">'+
                                                     '</div>'+
                                                 '</td>'+

                                                '</td>'+
                                             '</tr>'+
                                         '</table>');
            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
            var i=counter;

            $("#parent_cat" + counter ).change(function() {
                $me=$(this).val();

                $.get('loadsubcat.php?parent_cat=' + $me, function(data) {

                    $("#sub_cat" + i  ).html(data);
                });    
            });
            $("#parent_cat" + counter ).change(function() {
                $me=$(this).val();

            });
                $("#sub_cat" + i ).change(function() {
                    $me1=$(this).val();

                    $.get('material_type.php?parent_cat=' + $me + '& sub_cat=' + $me1 , function(data) {
                        $("#sub_cat11" + i ).html(data);
                });    
            });
            $("#sub_cat" + i).change(function() {
                    $me1=$(this).val();
            });
                $("#sub_cat11" + i).change(function() {
                    $me2=$(this).val();
                    $.get('stock_value5.php?parent_cat=' + $me + '& sub_cat=' + $me1 + '& sub_cat11=' + $(this).val() , function(data) {
                        $("#stock" + i).html(data);

                    });    
                });                    
            counter++;                
         });

         $("#removeButton").click(function () 
         {
            if(counter==2)
            {
                alert("No more Material Details to remove");
                return false;
               }   
            counter--;
            $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
         });
         $("#save").click(function () 
         {
            var msg = '';
            for(i=1; i<counter; i++)
            {
                     msg += $('#person' + i).val();
            }  
         });

    });

    $old(document).ready(function ($) {
        //initilize any plugins that need the older version of jquery
        $("#select").searchable();
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function openWin()
{
    var myWindow = window.open("new_material.php","","width=300,height=200");
}
function openWin1()
{
    var myWindow = window.open("new_make.php","","width=300,height=200");
}

function openWin4()
{
    var myWindow = window.open("new_material_type.php","","width=300,height=200");
}
function stopRKey(evt) { 
      var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null); 
      var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null); 
      if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;} 
    } 

    document.onkeypress = stopRKey; 
</script>

<title>Solution Infinite</title>
<style type="text/css">
font
{
    color:#FFFFFF
}
</style>

</head>

    <body>
    <form action="pdsave.php" method="post" name="quatation" id="quatation" >
    <input type="hidden" name="form_secret" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['FORM_SECRET'] ?>" />
    <div align="center"><font color="#FFFFFF" size="+1"><b>Quotation Form</b></font></div>
    <div class='ex'>
    <table  style="margin-top:15px;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div  style="width:150;height:20px; float:left; text-align:center">
                    <font size="+1">Date:</font>
                 </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px; width:250px;">
                     <?php                          
                           $fdate_default =$date;    
                           $todate_default =$date;
                           $myCalendar = new tc_calendar("fdate", true, false);     
                        $myCalendar->setIcon("../calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif");      
                        $myCalendar->setDate(date('d', strtotime($fdate_default))
                        , date('m', strtotime($fdate_default))
                        , date('Y', strtotime($fdate_default)));      
                        $myCalendar->setPath("../calendar/");     
                         $myCalendar->setYearInterval(1970, 2020);    
                           $myCalendar->setAlignment('left', 'bottom');        
                        $myCalendar->writeScript();    
                        $time=date("H:i:s");
                    ?>   
                <input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?php echo $time?>">
                 </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div  style="width:200;height:20px; float:left; text-align:center">
                    <font size="+1">Delivery Expected Date:</font>
                 </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px; width:250px;">
                     <?php                          
                           $myCalendar = new tc_calendar("todate", true, false);     
                        $myCalendar->setIcon("../calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif");      
                        $myCalendar->setDate(date('d', strtotime($todate_default))
                        , date('m', strtotime($todate_default))
                        , date('Y', strtotime($todate_default)));      
                        $myCalendar->setPath("../calendar/");     
                         $myCalendar->setYearInterval(1970, 2020);    
                           $myCalendar->setAlignment('left', 'bottom');        
                        $myCalendar->writeScript();    
                        $time=date("H:i:s");
                    ?>   
                <input type="text" name="expected_time" value="<?php echo $time?>">
                 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>          

    <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
        <table border='1px' BORDERCOLOR='#98AFC7' style="margin-top:15px;">
        <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="width:150;height:20px; float:left; text-align:center">
                        <font size="+1">Material:</font>
                     </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px;">
                        <select class="nav" name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat">
                            <?php echo $material;?>
                           </select> 
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="button1 black" type="button" value="new" onClick=      "openWin()">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="width:75;height:20px; float:left; text-align:center">
                        <font size="+1">Make:</font>
                     </div>
                </td>
                   <td>
                    <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px;">
                        <select class="nav" name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat"></select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>                     
                        <input type="button" class="button1 black" value="new" onClick="openWin1()">                       
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="margin-left:20px;">
                        <input type='button' value='Add' id='addButton' style="width:auto" >
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><input type='button' value='Remove' id='removeButton' style="width:auto" ></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border='1px' BORDERCOLOR='#98AFC7'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div  style="width:150;height:20px; float:left; text-align:center">
                        <font size="+1">Type:</font>
                     </div>
                </td>
                   <td>
                    <div style="margin-left:20px;">
                        <select class="nav" name="sub_cat11" id="sub_cat11"></select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>                     
                    <input type="button" class="button1 black" value="new" onClick="openWin4()">                   
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div  style="width:150;height:20px; float:left; text-align:center">
                        <font size="+1">Quantity:</font>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div  style="margin-left:20px; float:left;">        
                        <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div  id="stock" name="stock" style="width:150px;height:20px; float:left;text-align:center; margin-left:10px;">        
                    </div>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>
                    <div  style="width:100px;height:20px; margin-left:20px; text-align:center">
                        <font size="+1">Sales Detail:</font>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px;">
                        <textarea rows="2" cols="25" name="s_price" id="s_price"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px;width:100px;">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="s_including" id="including" value="including"><font size="+0">Including</font>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="s_including" id="excluding" value="excluding"><font size="+0">Excluding</font>
                        <select name="s_excluding_tax" id="s_excluding_tax" class="nav">
                            <?php echo $tax;?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>                   
            </tr>
        </div>
        </table>
    </div>

    <table align="center">
    <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="button1 blue"  />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="button1 blue" type="reset" value="Clear">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input  TYPE="Button" value="Close"  class="button1 blue" onClick="javascript:location.href=('dashboard.php');">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my html page I want to insert multiple column value and insert into database is perfectly but all material and maker value insert into single column but i want to insert value all product1 ,2,3 etc in different column if i select 3 times than 3 material in three different column it is possible because I am new in php and not getting solution properly 
Here my php code

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! It is clearly visible that you're pretty new in programming, but also have learned from a tutorial which is probably out-dated and contains bad practice. The `mysql` functions is deprecated (with other words, don't use it anymore in your new projects). Please use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead (google it). I recommend to lookup for more recent tutorials. Also, try to improve your answer (eg. remove non relevant code). Please check [_How do I ask_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide for more information.

Comment: here is my PHP Code http://codepad.org/S0HbvGAv

Comment: You can't still be using PHP's mysql_ API. How?